# Eigen perspective projection matrix

Tags: c++, opengl-es-2.0, eigen

I'm trying to create a perspective projection matrix for OpenGL. I know how to do it with a `float[16]` but for consistencies sake I'd like to use an Eigen matrix.

The [formula](http://openglbook.com/the-book/chapter-4-entering-the-third-dimension/) is:

```
    [ xScale   0                 0                        0               ]
P = [   0    yScale              0                        0               ]
    [   0      0    -(zFar+zNear)/(zFar-zNear) -2*zNear*zFar/(zFar-zNear) ]
    [   0      0                -1                        0               ]
```

Where:

```
yScale = cot(fovY/2)
xScale = yScale/aspectRatio
```

Since the formula is column-major and c-arrays are defined row-major, you would define a `float[16]` matrix with:

```
float P[16] = {
  xScale, 0, 0, 0,
  0, yScale, 0, 0,
  0, 0, -(zFar+zNear)/(zFar-zNear), -1
  0, 0, -2*zNear*zFar/(zFar-zNear), 0
};
```

So how exactly would I create a matrix like this with Eigen? Would I use an `Eigen::Affine3f` or a `Eigen::Matrix4f`? Looking at [the](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TutorialGeometry.html) [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TutorialMapClass.html), it's not apparent to me how to set individual cell values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, the simplest is to use the [comma initializer](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialAdvancedInitialization.html) syntax:

```
Eigen::Matrix4f pmat;
pmat << xScale, 0, 0, 0,
        0, yScale, 0, 0,
        0, 0, -(zFar+zNear)/(zFar-zNear), -1,
        0, 0, -2*zNear*zFar/(zFar-zNear), 0;
```

Comment: Eigen's Matrix4f is column-major, so I think it should be the transpose of this. (Eigen can be configured to be row-major like C 2D arrays with template parameters, but the Matrix4f is column-major.)

Comment: The comma initializer mechanism is agnostic to storage order.

Answer (score 1):

Setting individual cell values can be done simply with a paren, e.g. Matrix(0,0) = xScale; .